# Laravel. Как устроена навигация по сайту?

Tags: laravel, навигация, navigationcontroller, content, sidebar

Я очень начинающий в laravel. Хочу построить одностраничное приложение такого вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выборе пункта в main menu, меняется наполнение side menu
При выборе пункта в sude menu, меняется CONTENT

Я никак не могу понять принцип - надо передавать из главного меню какието парамеры, а по ним формировать боковое меню, или делать отдельные вьюхи на каждый пункт, или както манипулировать sections

Направьте в нужном направлении.
Спасибо

Comment: Смотря какого результата вы хотите добиться, можете сделать глобальную переменную, можете сделать на фронт фреймворке, можете использовать разные вьюхи... Можете делать что захотите....

Comment: В контенте будут таблицы из БД, наполнение которых будет зависеть от выбранных пунктов меню. Например: верхнее меню континенты, боковое - страны, контент - списки городов с населением, координатами и пр. Тогда, если использовать переменные, то глобальная ID континента, а из бокового вызывается таблица с ID страны. Так? Если я захочу выводить не список городов, а список рек, то завожу другую вьюху. Так?

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере нужно делать вывод .blade файла где у вас написано "Content". назовём его, к примеру, content.blade.php. `return view('content');` В файле content.blade.php должно быть примерной такое содержание:

```
@extends('side_menu')
@section('content')
    <div>Content</div>
@endsection
```

Файл side_menu.blade.php:

```
@extends('main_menu')
<span>side menu</span>
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
@section('side_menu')
    @yield('content')
@endsection
```

Файл main_menu.blade.php:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
@yield('side_menu')
```